# Passing custom headers in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am exploring options to pass custom/standard headers to downstream service using WSO2 Api Manager. 
I have gone through mediation documentation, and had play around with WSO2 developer studio as well. 
I see that the documentation of the latest version of API Manager- 3.0.0 and the actual product vary a lot and I ran into different issues as the WSO2 developer studio is still designed for older version of API Manager.

Can you guide me to proper documentation which holds true for API Manager 3.0.0 or a simple way to achieve header mapping for request and response from API Manager.

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/Extensions/adding-mediation-extensions/

APIM 3.0.0 documentation for adding a mediation extension